# How to add additional data in my JQUERY submit?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

In my razor view, I'm using a `Html.BeginForm`. In it I have two elements where when I set clic, should submit the form but I need to add an additional string parameter.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    ...
}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string parameter, QuizCompletedViewModel q)  //FormCollection f)
    {            
        ...
        if (button.Equals("d"))
        {
            ...
            return RedirectToAction("ShowResults", new { testId = Quiz.QuizId, answeredTest = answeredId });
        }
        else
        {
            ...
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
        }
    }
```

So, in my jquery function I utilize `$("#element").submit()` and the parameter `parameter` always is null (and that's normal). How can I add additional data for `parameter` using JQUERY?

NOTE: I'm not using AJAX.

Comment: What additional data? from where? what is `#element` - the form or some other element?

Comment: How are you passing the model?

Comment: @BhushanFirake Using the same whole model that my razor view

Comment: @tvanfosson #element is the form, sorry. I mean pass the data something like this:  { parameter: "d", q: $("#form").serialize() }

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - add additional parameters on submit (NOT ajax)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530635/jquery-add-additional-parameters-on-submit-not-ajax)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your form sumbit try like this:

```
        $("form").submit(function(){
           $.ajax({     
                type: 'POST',  
                url: "/Quiz/Index",
                dataType: "json",
                data: $("form").serialize() + '&parameter=param1' ,   
                success: function () { 
                    alert("Successful"); 
                }
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                }

            }); 
        });
```

Hope it helps.

---

**Edit**

Try like this in your jQuery function:

```
$('form').append('&param=a');
```

Comment: Am I missing something? It's still passing a NULL value in `parameter` value:                 $("#form").append('button=a').submit();

Comment: can you see any querystring's in your url of browser when you submit the form

Comment: With you last answer, I can achieve more information since your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761051/adding-dynamic-parameters-with-html-beginform-and-jquery-submit

Comment: Wow! the number of times I monkeyed around with hidden elements, and that was all I had to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could add a hidden input with the name and value you require in your form. This value will be submitted along with all the other form items.

```
<input type="hidden" name="someName" value="someValue" />
```

Edit for comment:

If you give each of your submit buttons the value as an attribute you could grab it in the click handler and then append a hidden field with the value inside the form. Something like:

```
$(function(){
   $('#form input[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
       var val = this.getAttribute("data-param");
       $(this).closest('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="param" value="' + val + '" />");
   });
});
```

Untested, just a hunch. Hope that the form submit event does not get fired before the button click event. Also you will need to handle the enter event and key press etc.

Why don't you want to use ajax?

Comment: Well, imagine that I have two buttons in my razor view, one of them should send "d" as `parameter` and the another send "a" as `parameter`

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments, the easiest thing for you to do is make your buttons of type `submit` and give them a `name`.  If they have a `name`, the `value` of the button that is clicked will be sent automatically with the form post, see: [sending form's submit button's value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297763/sending-forms-submit-buttons-value)

Example:

When the `a` button is clicked, `parameter` will be posted with value `a`.  Likewise for `b` and `c`.  If the `none` button is clicked, no value will be sent and `parameter` will be `null` (shown for demonstration purposes, you may not need this).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Quiz", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    ...

    <input type="submit" value="a" name="parameter" />
    <input type="submit" value="b" name="parameter" />
    <input type="submit" value="c" name="parameter" />
    <input type="submit" value="none" />
}
```