# Grabbing values from outside of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to grab the code from another part of my page without putting it in the form… is there a way to do it with JavaScript/jQuery?

Essentially, I’d like to take the value from here:

```html
<div class='span5' style='margin-left:0px !important;'>
    <label for='area0'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='area' id='area' value='West Palm Beach' style='margin-top:-5px !important;'>
        West Palm Beach
    </label>
</div>
```

And put it into the form that exists elsewhere on the same page.

```html
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="final_form" action="send_mail.php">
    MORE INPUTS
</form>
```

Is there a simple JavaScript way to do this? I just want to take the value if the checkbox is checked and assign it as a value within the form so that it gets passed on to send_mail.php.

Comment: There sure is. What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I could use more information. What triggers the "grab"? A button click? Where is the button? How would you like the value to be put in the form? In a hidden input, maybe?

Comment: Do you want to move the value itself, putting it in a new container (div? input? the middle of a paragraph?) or do you want to clone/move some element and put it elsewhere?  A sample of before and after code would probably illustrate this very clearly.

Comment: I want to add it as a value that's not displayed in the other form, but will get passed on to send_mail.php

Comment: You'll need to add a hidden input to the form OR submit the form via ajax and add the extra value in your javascript code. See Rafaels response for the hidden input approach, see my response for the ajax approach. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a hidden field inside the form, like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="area_is_checked" name="area_is_checked" />
```

Then use JQuery to get the checkbox value before submitting the form:

```
$("#final_form").submit(function () {
  $("#area_is_checked").val($("#area").is(':checked'));
  return true;
});
```

Comment: The return true makes sure that the form is submitted after the function. I just put it in there for the user to know that there's the possibility to return false and avoid submitting.

Comment: Within the php, should I be calling 'area' or 'area_is_checked'

Comment: I got that part...I want to actually call that value though (West Palm Beach). How do I do that?

Comment: This is only returning true every time...even when I plugin a different return value.

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

```
$('form#new-location').append($("div#move-me-please"));
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwxPt/

Edit: since the answer was edited after I wrote this:

If you really can't add a hidden field to the form, you can still add extra data to your form when the user submits it by submitting it via ajax. See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721545/how-to-add-additional-data-in-my-jquery-submit) for more info.

Comment: OP does not want to put that in the form

Comment: @Sushanth-- OP wants to know how. seeing as he didn't explain what is to be moved where, then this is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-form) (works in at least Opera 9.5+, Safari 5.1+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 10+):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='area' id='area' value='West Palm Beach' style='margin-top:-5px !important;' form="final_form">
```

There is a Modernizr test for it. You can however still use the `form` attribute, and then search for those instead of hard-coding the external inputs like the following:

```
$('#final_form').on('submit', function() {
    $('input[form=' + this.id + ']').each(function() {
        var externalInput = $(this);
        // then same as below.
    });
});
```

---

Or using jQuery instead of the `form` attribute:

```
$('#final_form').on('submit', function() {
    var externalInput = $('#area');
    var name = externalInput.attr('name');
    /* use existing */
    var hidden = $(this).find('input[name=' + name + ']');
    /* create a new hidden field */
    if ( ! hidden.length ) {
        hidden = $('<input>', {
            name: name
        }).appendTo(this);
    }
    hidden.val(externalInput.is('[type=checkbox]') ? externalInput.prop('checked') : externalInput.val())
});
```

This will create a hidden field or, if you're doing validation on it and it might not actually submit, use one that was already added. This requires not update to the HTML.

Comment: Dies IE support that yet?

Comment: IE does not support the `form` attribute, but the jquery method should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is..

```
    <div id="inputsBlock" class='span5' style='margin-left:0px !important;'>
    <label for='area0' style="display: none;">
        <input type='checkbox' name='area' id='area' value='West Palm Beach' style='margin-top:-5px !important;'>
        West Palm Beach
    </label>
</div>
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="final_form" action="send_mail.php">
MORE INPUTS
</form>

<script>
$('#inputsBlock').children().clone().css({display: 'none'}).appendTo($('#final_form'));
</script>
```

Comment: Would this still be assigned to the value of 'area' in the send_mail.php?

Comment: Yes.. It will be passed along when you submit.

Comment: This is making it display in the form. How do I hide it but still pass that value along to send_mail.php.

Comment: Edited.. See the answer now. Just Add display: none; to elements to be hidden

Comment: Isn't that display none going to hide it where it should actually display, outside the form?

Comment: Yes. Oh you want it to be visible outside the form.. I have added a fix.. see the answer now.

Comment: Why am I calling the whole checkbox? I only want to call the value of that checkbox when the checkbox is checked.